# Adding a fade effect to CSS/JS tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys, I got this JS code and want to add a slight fade effect when switching tabs, so it looks a little bit smoother.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  initTabs();
});

function initTabs() {
  $('#tabMenu a').bind('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var thref = $(this).attr("href").replace(/#/, '');
  $('#tabMenu a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('#tabContent div.content').removeClass('active');
  $('#'+thref).addClass('active');
  });
}
```

And this is the corresponding HTML:

```
<ul id="tabMenu">
    <li><a id="tab_1" class="active" href="#1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab_2" class="" href="#2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabContent">
    <div id="1" class="content active"></div>
    <div id="2" class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be handy if you provided the CSS too, here's a JSFiddle with the code as you entered it - edit and re-save!  http://jsfiddle.net/HyeU2/

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery UI tabs? They come prepacked with this already accomplished. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: updated the jsfiddle. Don't want to use jquery UI, I already have the jQuery framework included and don't want to use a second library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

replace:

```
$('#tabContent div.content').removeClass('active');
$('#'+thref).addClass('active');
```

by:

```
$('#tabContent div.content[id!='+thref+']').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#'+thref).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [FadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [FadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) methods.

Using them is fairly straightforward:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: yes, I tested a few things with fadeIn and fadeOut, but couldn't get it to work :\